Как команды процессора кодируются в ячейках памяти?
Недавно я начал изучать устройство компьютера и столкнулся с таким вопросом. Я понимаю, что процессор получает данные и инструкции из памяти по шине. При этом память представляет собой последовательность ячеек размером в один байт (8 бит), где каждая ячейка может хранить число от 0 до 255. Но мне не совсем ясно, как именно команда процессора умещается в один байт. Объясните, пожалуйста, как в одном байте можно закодировать инструкцию для процессора?

например, простой связкой: значение - команда

Вы правы, обычно команда в 1 байт не умещается  (исключения существуют). Но что вам мешает прочесть несколько байт, а уже потом начинать исполнение команды? Впрочем,   обычно мы читаем по шине не 1 байт (8 бит) за раз, а больше (скажем, от 32 бит до 256 в зависиости от типа компьютера). Поэтому за одно обращение к памяти в буфер команд считывается даже не одна команда.

Инструкция сама по себе может быть представлена в виде битов, где каждый бит(группа битов) отвечает за часть информации, например: в 8-битном процессоре 00000001 - это сложение, а 00000010 - вычитание. Отсюда и следует, что, если у нас есть 4 бита для операции и 4 бита для операндов, то можно закодировать 16 операций(ну или их  комбинаций). А если возможные значения от 0 до 255, то получается можно закодировать 256 инструкций, где как раз каждая инструкция занимает один байт

но следует учесть, что это для 8-битного процессора все так легко)) для x86, как знаю, команда может начинаться с одного байта, который указывает на операцию, а после уже следуют доп. байты, которые указывают на операнды или параметры. в общем, все зависит от архитектуры процессора

Существует ли обобщённая таблица, в которой можно найти информацию о том, как и какие команды процессора кодируются?

@Владислав гуглится по «x86 opcode». Например, вот.

Очень благодарен! Хорошего времени суток)
